# sftpd - Is it possible to run a script when an sftp session ended?

Tags: sftp

I want to set up an sftp server in a docker container, using https://github.com/atmoz/sftp

My intention is to allow some users to send me files. As soon as they uploaded their files and ended their session, I want a script to run which allows me to process their files.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I hope this post help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/execute-command-in-sftp-connection-through-script

Comment: Unfortunately not at all. The script has to run in my sftp container and should be the same script or any user connecting. So when a user uploaded their file to their ~user/inbox directory and disconnect, my sftp server kicks in and moves their file to another location or does something else with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSSH SSH server used by that container doesn't have a feature like this built in. However, if you're willing to alter the docker image, it can be made to work. OpenSSH includes an SFTP server implemented as a standalone program which can be invoked when a client requests an SFTP session. You could arrange to run a script instead, which runs the standalone SFTP server followed by whatever custom logic you want to add.

The basic process would be as follows:

1. Alter the container to include the `sftp-server` program. It looks like you need to add the `openssh-sftp-server` package.
2. Write a script which does what you want:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Invoke sftp-server
   /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
   # Do your postprocessing
   some command...
   ```

   You will need to supply the correct path to the sftp-server program within the container, and add your logic after sftp-server runs. Add the script to the container and make sure it's executable.
3. Alter the `sshd_config` file that's included in the image. Replace the line "Subsystem sftp internal-sftp" with something like this:

   ```
    Subsystem sftp /path/to/my/sftp/wrapper
   ```

   Basically, this line tells the SSH server process what command to run when a client requests an SFTP session. Everything after "Subsystem sftp" should be a command to run. You want it to run your sftp-server wrapper script.

Once you've done this, the SSH server process should run your wrapper script for SFTP sessions. Your script in turn will run the sftp-server program, followed by your special logic.

Note this solution isn't really compatible with running SFTP in a chroot environment (using the SSHD ChrootDirectory option). The usual way of setting up chroot SFTP precludes running an external process for SFTP sessions.

Comment: Thanks @Kenster for your very good explanation. I think this is too much effort and, as it's not possible with chroot, I better stick to my previous solution to pull the files when I need them.